# Quantrix: How to enter the label within Pie Chart in Quantrix Matrix

Tags: charts

I am using Quantrix software. I am unable to get the label of the pie chart inside the specific region for that Label.
I get the label and the value associated with the region outside the Pie Chart. I am able to connect them with a line.
I want both the value and the label to be within the Pie Chart.

I got the Pie Chart by clicking on Insert Chart View -> right click-> Show data labels -> Data label.
and right click -> connect labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shank,

Right now there is no way to have the values and labels be inside of the pieces of the pie. You are correct that when using a pie chart you must have the values outside the pie and you can connect the labels with "connect labels".

It might be worth posting on the [Quantrix Forums](http://forum.quantrix.com/) to see if any users have found a workaround.

Kind Regards,

James

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried registering at Quantrix forum but unfortunately there server is down. Doesn't register me.

Comment: Question : Is it possible to hide one of the bars in Quantrix Bar graph or select only the columns that I want the graph to project.

Comment: @Shank apologies for the slow response - you can simply use the table view below the chart and collapse the columns you don't want to see on the chart - this will automatically be reflected in the chart. Look out for our new Quantrix specific Question/Answer site coming soon!